# OpenLDAP : adding ldif output error

Tags: linux, openldap

Here is my ldif file :

```
dn: ou=export,dc=XXXXX,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: autoumountMap
ou: export

dn: cn=/,ou=export,dc=XXXXX,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: automount
cn: /
automountInformation: -rw,nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid 10.0.0.2:/home/&
```

When I try to add it, I got the following error :

```
SERVER2:/etc/ldap/ldif# ldapadd -x -f addnfs.ldif -W -D cn=admin,dc=XXXXX,dc=local

Enter LDAP Password: 

adding new entry "ou=export,dc=XXXXX,dc=local"

ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)

    additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

Any idea why ?
I followed that tutorial :
 http://damstux.free.fr/wiki/index.php?title=Autofs%2C_LDAP_et_NFS

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

objectClass: auto**u**mountMap

correct:

objectClass: automountMap

In another cause, I think your slapd.conf not include autofs.schema.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem (syntax error).
the autofs.schema is included in slapd.conf.

Now I got the following error :
adding new entry "ou=export,dc=mactelecom,dc=local"
ldap_add: No such object (32)

Comment: Please add the following entry to your directory server at first.
dn: dc=mactelecom,dc=local
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: mactelecom
dc: mactelecom